# How to use for loop in class for user inputs?

Tags: python

I have created employee details using class by giving pre defined inputs. I'm not able to store the results into a dict. I need to write it as a csv.   I would be thankful if you could help me, as I'm a novice in python

Here are my codes:

#### Is it correct way to use for loop in classes?

```
class Employee():
    def main(self,name,idno,position,salary):

        self.name=name
        self.idno=idno
        self.position=position
        self.salary = salary

    def input(self):
        n=int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees:"))
        for i in range(n):
            self.name=raw_input("Name:")
            self.idno=raw_input("Idno:")
            self.position=raw_input("position:")
            self.salary=raw_input("salary:")

            print("Name:", self.name, "Idno:", self.idno, "position:", self.position,
                  "salary:", self.salary)

if __name__=='__main__':
        result=Employee()
        result.input()
```

Comment: I don't think your class structure will work how you expect it to.  I'd go and read your OOP tutorial again.  Edit: or Empldb is just badly named...

Comment: I have edited my question with another solution I tried. Pls check it @RoadieRich

Comment: You can't really do it like that, you'd be better off moving the loop outside your class, under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section.

Comment: Or you can create a separate class, say an `EmployeeDb`, (which is what I thought you were going for to start with) which handles creating and storing `Employee` instances.  You might still be better off moving your input loop outside the classes, though.

Comment: Thats what I have tried in my second solution

Comment: My 2nd solution works for getting n inputs using class, but I couldnt store the outputs in a dict.

Comment: I have removed the solution to reduce confusion

Comment: **No**, that's not the right way. Creating a bunch of `Employee` instances should not be done in the class itself. The class should only be concerned with one instance, `self`. Generally a group of instances will be held in a container of some sort, like a `list`. Filling the container is where you might want a `for` loop. Each iteration could call the built-in `input` function multiple times getting the pieces of information required to create one instance of the class. One those datum are gathered, an instance could then be created and added to the container—wash and repeat.

Comment: Can you explain me with the solution or an example? I'm not getting you @martineau

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you're class will be working like you intend it to. Since you're constantly overwriting the class  variables, there is no point in entering more than one employee, as the class can currently only save information on one employee. I would consider saveing employees as dictionarys and have those dictionaries saved as a list in your Employee(s) class.

```
class Employees():
    all_employees = [{...}, {...}]
    dict_keys = ["name", "idno", "position",...]
    def input(self):
        counter = 0
        n = input("Number of employees: ")
        while counter < n:
            new_employee = dict()
            for key in dict_keys:
                new_employee[key] = raw_input("{}: ".format(key))
            all_employees.append(new_employee)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = Employees()
    e.input()
```

Comment: I want to get 'n' inputs and for those n inputs, i would like to give details which should get updated in an empty dict.

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates what I was saying in my comment about using a `for` loop *outside* of the class:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, idno, position, salary):
        self.name=name
        self.idno=idno
        self.position=position
        self.salary = salary

    def print_data(self):
        print("Name:", self.name, "Idno:", self.idno, "position:", self.position,
              "salary:", self.salary)

if __name__=='__main__':

    def input_employee_data():
        print('Enter data for an employee')
        name = raw_input("Name:")
        idno = raw_input("Idno:")
        position = raw_input("position:")
        salary = raw_input("salary:")
        print('')
        return name, idno, position, salary

    employees = list()
    n = int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees:"))
    for i in range(n):
        name, idno, position, salary = input_employee_data()
        employee = Employee(name, idno, position, salary)
        employees.append(employee)

    print('List of employess')
    for employee in employees:
        employee.print_data()
```